# no Anti aliasing in Input textfield in AIR for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

Input textfield in AIR for iOS looks really ugly when it does not have focus. As soon as i click it though anti aliasing kicks in and the font looks smooth as it should. When it looses focus the font again looks horrible.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS flash **Textfield** has quite unpredicatble behaviors. One work-around is to use **TextInput** component which gives pretty decent results in comparison to **TextField**.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion - i'll check it out first thing in the morning.

Comment: Testing it out right now. Do you know if it is possible to make the component use multiline?

Comment: If you need a multiline text field, use the TextArea component.